# Having trouble with a simple while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I've been trying to create a simple program in python in which the user is asked for their postcode until it contains both letters and numbers.
This is the code I have so far:

```
num = False
letter = False
while num == False and letter == False:
    postcode = input("what is your postcode? ")
    for i in postcode:
        if i.isalpha:
            letter = True
        if i.isdigit:
            num = True
```

When I run the program it doesn't ask me for my postcode even when it is wrong. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using a for loop?

Comment: I wanted the loop to check through ‘postcode’ for both letters and numbers

Comment: You forgot to _call_ the functions. `i.isalpha` is not the same as `i.isalpha()`

Comment: I also think you mean `while num == False or letter == False`.  You want to continue if either of them is false.  It might be simpler to write `while not (num and letter)` which makes your logic a little clearer.

Comment: If I may critique your question, what you meant is "it doesn't RE-ask me for my postcode".  It always asks you, exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the methods!

```
if i.isalpha():  # note the ()
    # ...
if i.isdigit():
    # ...
```

`i.isalpha` is just the `method` object (which is always truthy). Only calling it will produce the real `bool` you are looking for.

You could actually make this more concise, all the while not manually calling the methods and not having to maintain/reset all those variables:

```
while True:
    postcode = input("what is your postcode? ")
    if any(map(str.isalpha, postcode)) and any(map(str.isdigit, postcode)):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to see all the problems.

```
num = False
letter = False
while not(num and letter):
    num = False
    letter = False
    user_input = input("What is your postcode? ")
    x = user_input[0]
    y = user_input[1]
    print(x.isalpha())
    print(y.isdigit())
    if x.isalpha():
        letter = True
    if y.isdigit():
        num = True
    print(num, letter)
        
print("You are in")
```

You don't reset the values of `num` and `letter` each time.

In your original you are changing a string you are iterating over.

And as someone else pointed out, you need to call functions with `()`.

A good attempt though. There are many ways this could be done. Mine is just one "fix".